# Apply style only to <select> tag excluding <option> in HTML

Tags: css, angular, stylesheet

I want to apply style only to parent `<select>` tag excluding its `<option>` children.

See the code below:
I want that whenever the first option is selected, my style `'highlight'` should to applied to `<select>`. Other `<option>` tags should remain unaffected.

I want to do it inline rather than using component level css.
It is due to some design/coding guidelines limitations as all styles are fetched from a pre-defined master style sheet and adding new styles is very rare.

```
  <select [ngClass]="{ 'highlight': selectedUser === undefined }" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined">
      Select User
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">
      {{ user.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you're using a pre-defined global style sheet, you have to override the style for the option tag being inherited from that rules.